# Do you lose additional turn if sent to jail by Community Chest?

Tags: monopoly

I've read through the rule book and don't see this specific situation mentioned.

If you roll doubles and land on a Community Chest square, and the card draw is a Go To Jail card, are you able to roll again to try to get out of jail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you end up in jail your turn ends and you have 3 turns to roll doubles to get out of jail or pay the $50 fee. The turn ending doesn't matter if you had additional dice rolls due to getting doubles.

I bolded the section in the rules that talks about turns ending.

https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf

> “JAIL”… You land in Jail when… (1) your token lands on the space
> marked “Go to Jail”; (2) you draw a card marked “Go to Jail”; or
> (3) you throw doubles three times in succession.
> When you are sent to Jail you cannot collect your $200 salary in that
> move since, regardless of where your token is on the board, you must
> move it directly into Jail. **Yours turn ends when you are sent to Jail.**
> If you are not “sent” to Jail but in the ordinary course of play land
> on that space, you are “Just Visiting,” you incur no penalty, and you
> move ahead in the usual manner on your next turn.
> You get out of Jail by… (1) throwing doubles on any of your next
> three turns; if you succeed in doing this you immediately move
> forward the number of spaces shown by your doubles throw; even
> though you had thrown doubles, you do not take another turn;
> (2) using the “Get Out of Jail Free” card if you have it; (3) purchasing
> the “Get Out of Jail Free” card from another player and playing it;
> (4) paying a fine of $50 before you roll the dice on either of your next
> two turns.
> If you do not throw doubles by your third turn, you must pay the
> $50 fine. You then get out of Jail and immediately move forward the
> number of spaces shown by your throw.
> Even though you are in Jail, you may buy and sell property, buy
> and sell houses and hotels and collect rents